# React native project doesn't run Android

Tags: javascript, react-native

I've started React-Native programing recently. When I run "**npx react-native run-android**" in my own terminal, the build is failed but, it is run by Android Studio successfully.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L7xBK.png)

I' ll be thankfull of guiding me

Comment: So this are to different problems. One nothing to do with the other. I suggest you to separate them in different Questions/Topic otherwise you wont get your expected answers and probably you will get some downvotes. My 2 cents on running gradle from command line is that you have not set JAVA_HOME properly

Answer (score 0):

I could solve this problem, when added this

> org.gradle.java.home = **Address of JDK in your mac**

to **gradle.properties**